# Why does the water not flow on this tub

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, water, fluid-statics

I found this problem on Brilliant and it's quite interesting because you have 2 tubes that are connected and on both ends they are put under a different pressure:

[image: Picture of the situation]

On the upper hole there is less pressure than on the lower hole, which I then thought, since water moves from lower pressure to higher pressure then it must flow in this tube from up to down, but Brilliant says it doesn't move at all! How is that possible if it exists a difference in pressure?

Comment: A pressure difference alone does not necessarily cause water to flow. For example, in a glass of water stilling on a table, the pressure at the top of the cup is less than the pressure at the bottom of the cup, but water does not flow "up the cup."

Comment: Water doesn't move from lower pressure to higher pressure, it moves from higher pressure to lower pressure. Otherwise the water in your garden hose would go back up the hose into the tap and the pipe where the water pressure is higher.

Comment: @hft in that glass of water case, it wouldn't move due to gravity counteracting on it, right? The same case it happens here

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, water flows from higher pressure to lower pressure, not the other way around. The reason it won't flow (in either direction, even if you start with the tube filled with water) is that the pressure difference, which pushes water from bottom to top, is cancelled by gravity, which pulls water from top to bottom. The reason these forces cancel exactly is that the pressure difference is itself caused by gravity. Pressure lower in the fluid builds up until it exactly cancels the gravitational force pulling down on the liquid above it.